# Analyse source code in Java using Python?

Tags: java, python, static-analysis

i would like to create a source code analyser for Java Project (like FindBugs and other static analysis programs) that would be able to detect certain method calls.

I would prefer to do it using Python, but any advice would be great !

I'm going to start by studying the [FindBugs](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/) source code, but if anyone could explain to me the underlying concepts and if it's easily do-able, i would be really grateful.

Thank you for your time.

Olivier.

Comment: Java tools are usually written in Java. Maybe with Jython you can at least re-use some of the existing libraries (for parsing, AST generation and such).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the book : Language implementation Patterns. It is a very accessible book out there and you can gauge the effort that will be required to achieve what you want to achieve

- http://www.pragprog.com/titles/tpdsl/language-implementation-patterns